# Unity C# Gradle Build Failed

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build.gradle

I'm making a mobile 3D game called Ptaszory. I wanted to try to build the game for Android. I get errors. I have no clue what it means or what should I do.

The unity Version I'm using is: 2021.3.24f1

This is my External Tools setup:[image]

My build settings:
[image]

My gradle and java: (not sure if this information is necessary here to solve the problem)
[image]

THE ERROR:
1.

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':launcher:classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools:common:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.0.1 > com.android.tools:repository:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.0.1
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.0/asm-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.0/asm-7.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/7.0/asm-analysis-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/7.0/asm-analysis-7.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/7.0/asm-commons-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/7.0/asm-commons-7.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/7.0/asm-util-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/7.0/asm-util-7.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/6.0.3/proguard-gradle-6.0.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/6.0.3/proguard-gradle-6.0.3.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:4.0.1-6197926
> > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.10.0/protobuf-java-3.10.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.10.0/protobuf-java-3.10.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.10.0.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.10.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.10.0/protobuf-java-util-3.10.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.10.0/protobuf-java-util-3.10.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.3.0-rc2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/crypto/tink/tink/1.3.0-rc2/tink-1.3.0-rc2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/crypto/tink/tink/1.3.0-rc2/tink-1.3.0-rc2.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/7.0/asm-tree-7.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/7.0/asm-tree-7.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.0.1
> > Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1
> > Could not resolve com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre.
> Required by:
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools:common:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.0.1
> project :launcher > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.0.1
> > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/28.1-jre/guava-28.1-jre.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/28.1-jre/guava-28.1-jre.pom'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderExcepti`

I tryied various versions of Gradle: 6.1.1, 8.2.1, 6.9.2.

Comment: It looks like it is an issue with the Kotlin version and not the Gradle version, in the error it says ```1.3.72. Required by: project :launcher``` and in your screenshot it says. ```Kotlin: 1.3.61```

Comment: Try updating the version of the Kotlin and check.

Comment: I have changed gradle to 6.5, which has embedded kotlin version 1.3.72. and I get the same error.

Comment: What does it says, in the version command?

Comment: I updated the project to Unity 2022.3 and all external tools to be compatible with it, and now build works.

Comment: I have to say when it comes to the external SKDs Unity can be stubborn with the version.

Answer (score 0):

Download and try Android SDKs through Android Studio. I had experienced the same issue and resolved it this way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).